# Visual Studio Addin for VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-addins

I was looking at one of the webcasts and found that class name had a small class diagram image beside it and all methods had lines, and all if or for loops had highligted lines so it makes them very clear where they end. Where can I get this addin from....?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a screen shot from the web cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a DevExpress Addin

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/

it has many visual aspects

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/Visualization.xml this is a number of screen shots